# ¿Cómo evitar la manipulación de agregar productos al carro de la compra mediante parámetros de la URL?

Tags: php, array

Quizás esto evitar la manipulación de los parámetros de la URL no sea solucionable y no pueda ser evitado, pero una inseguridad que me la han dado a saber.

Lo cual cualquier persona puede agregar productos al carro de la compra modificando el valor de la url por ejemplo:

```
http://example.com/updatecart.php?itemId=1
http://example.com/updatecart.php?itemId=11
http://example.com/updatecart.php?itemId=10
http://example.com/updatecart.php?itemId=20
http://example.com/updatecart.php?itemId=9
```

De esa manera directa un usuario agrega productos al carro de la compra, quizas no sea tan vulnerable, pero existe alguna forma de evitar esas manipulaciones

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
session_start();

$itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : "";



if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_POST['qtyupdate'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qtyupdate']); $i++) {
        $key = $_POST['arr_key_' . $i];
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_POST['qtyupdate'][$i];
    }

} else {
    $qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : 1;
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        $_SESSION['qty'][] = array();
    }
    if (in_array($itemId, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_SESSION['qty'][$key] + $qty;
    } else {
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $itemId);
        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $qty;
    }
}
header('location:cart.php');

?>
```

Comment: Puedes cambiar tu GET por un POST

Comment: @PakLei Tengo una curiosidad al cambiarlo por método post, tendría que cambiar la etiqueta <a> por un formulario y, si se íntegra Ajax para agregar productos al carro de la compra.

Comment: así es, tendrías que cambiar el link por un request con parámetros. Ajax puede enviar peticiones con los parámetros como lo necesitas.

Comment: Podrías agregar una key a tu GET, crea un archivo con una tarea programada que cada x tiempo el servidor acceda a ese archivo php que cambiará la key, haces un include a ese php y que verifique si la key es correcta, dime si entendiste y si no sabes cómo hacerlo, dime y te hago una respuesta más elaborada.

Comment: Hola @Patrick Podrían ayudarme con la integración de Ajax, y todo aquello que me mencionas parece muy interesante pero no se como hacerlo me ayudas

Comment: @PakLei entonces la mejor opción sería usar ajax, aparte así ve mucho mejor, más dinámico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando una "key" o "token" de esta manera:

Creamos el archivo php "crearkey.php":

```
<?php
$caracteres = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
for($x = 0; $x < 10 ; $x++){
    $key = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres), 1);
    $keytxt = "key.txt"; 
        if(file_exists($keytxt)){
            $modifykey = fopen($keytxt, "w+");
            fwrite($modifykey, $key, 10);
            fclose($modifykey);
        }

        else{
            $createkey = fopen($keytxt, "w+");
            fwrite($createkey, $key, 10);
            fclose($createkey);
        }
    }

?>
```

Este creara un txt con el key, el nombre del txt puede ser modificado en la variable $keytxt.

Ahora creamos el archivo "key.php" que leera el txt y guardara la variable con la key

```
<?php
$keytxt = "key.txt";
$leerkey = fopen($keytxt, "r");
$key = fread($leerkey, filesize($keytxt));
fclose($leerkey);
?>
```

Ahora solo basta con incluir esto en nuestra pagina "http://example.com/updatecart.php", osea en tu archivo "updatecart.php"

```
<?php
include("key.php"); //Incluimos el php que contiene la key
if(isset($_GET["key"])){ //Comparamos si el url de la pagina contiene "key=lakeycreada" ejemplo: http://example.com/updatecart.php?itemId=12&key=lakeycreada
    $urlkey = $_GET["key"];// Obtenemos la key de la url con GET
    if($urlkey == $key) { // Comparamos la key obtenida por el URL con la key que contiene el archivo key.php
        echo "agregado al carrito con exito"; //Damos un mensaje si la key era correcta (se puede quitar en caso de no querer)
    }
    else{
        echo "no se pudo agregar al carrito"; //Damos un mensaje de error si la key no era correcta (se puede quitar en caso de no querer)
    }
}
else {
    $urlkey = ""; // Si la pagina no contiene "key=lakeycreada" en su URL, la variable urlkey es creada con contenido vacio
    echo "no se pudo agregar al carrito"; //Damos un mensaje de error porque la key no existia (se puede quitar en caso de no querer)
}
?>
```

A los enlaces de tu carrito debes agregarle un id mas, tu tienes "itemId" y debes agregarle uno mas que sera "key", ejemplo: "http://example.com/updatecart.php?itemId=1&key=lakeycreada"
Ejemplo:

```
<?php
include("key.php");
echo "http://example.com/updatecart.php?itemId=".$itemId."&key=".$key;
?>
```

Luego desde el cpanel de tu host debes crear una tarea programada o cron job que entre a "http://example.com/ruta/crearkey.php" cada x tiempo, pueden ser minutos, como horas o dias, lo recomendable seria 1 o 2 minutos...

Edit: ¿Como crear la tarea programada?

1.- Abre el cPanel y busca la opcion "Cron Jobs"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Elegimos con que dominio se realizara la tarea programada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- Apretamos "alter crons"

4.- Ponemos cada cuantos minutos o horas se ejecutara la tarea (entrar a crearkey.php para crear una nueva key) y ponermos la url donde esta el archivo php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5.- Le damos a add cron

Y listo! Ya tendrias todo solucionado.

Comment: Hola @Patrick Gracias por el ejemplo :)

Comment: No hay de que! Saludos @Lily